# How to handle token authentication in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, token

Suppose I have API for login, log out. I am using Token Authentication. 
I have react component name Login. I can call API and I am getting token. But, I am not understanding how to save the token in a browser until log out or automatically destroy token after a moment.

Comment: You can use both cookie and localstorage. You can check if the client support localstorage if not use cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a storage module and check for available storage in client's browser.

```
import LocalStorage from "./localstorage"
import Cookie from "./cookie"

// Function to check availability of `localStorage`
function storageAvailable() {
    try {
        var storage = window["localStorage"],
            x = '__storage_test__';
        storage.setItem(x, x);
        storage.removeItem(x);
        return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}

export default function Storage() {
  return storageAvailable() ? LocalStorage : Cookie
}
```

Using above module:

```
function login(redirect = '/home') {
  // set your session data
  storage.set({email, id})

  // redirection
  window.location.href = redirect
}

function logout(redirect = "/") {
  storage.clear()

  // redirection
  window.location.href = redirect
}
const Session = {
  login,
  logout
}

export default Session
```

Now you can simply use your `Session` module for login and logout as `Session.login()` and `Session.logut()` respectively.

How to use cookie: 
[How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

How to use localStorage: [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: You imported from "./localstorage". So, do I need to write anything for localstorage?

Comment: ".localstorage" and "./cookie" are modules for setting localstorage and cookie. You can create getter and setter for setting and getting storage data. I have added links on how to use localstorage and cookie.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Yes "./localstorage" . is your actual code that will set your storage data. I just showed you an abstract way of doing it properly. 
You can set your authentication token or any data you need after login in your storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `universal-cookie` package to set it in the cookie,

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set('token', this.token, { path: '/' });
```

Don't forget to import(or require) `Cookies` from `universal-cookie`.

You can retrieve it back using :

```
cookies.get('token');
```

Refer to https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie

You can save it in local storage as well :

```
localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
```

But saving in the cookie would be a better idea, refer to :

[Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)